# Точки в словах автора

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, точка-с-запятой

Писала прямую речь, и вызвал у меня сомнение вот такой вопрос: могут ли слова автора состоять из нескольких предложений? Например.

*— Прямая речь, — слова автора. Слова автора, — прямая речь.*

То есть фактически слова автора представляют собой несколько законченных мыслей. Но пунктуационно это возможно? Или вместо точки лучше поставить точку с запятой или же просто запятую?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, такой вариант возможен, в качестве примера можно привести немного отредактированный текст из Тургенева:

«Странный человек этот лекарь?» — думала она, лежа в своей великолепной постели, на кружевных подушках, под легким шелковым одеялом... Анна Сергеевна наследовала от отца частицу его наклонности к роскоши. Она очень любила своего грешного, но доброго отца, а он обожал ее, дружелюбно шутил с ней, как с ровней, и доверялся ей вполне, советовался с ней. Мать свою она едва помнила. И она повторила про себя: «Странный этот лекарь!»